# setOnItemClickListener on Gridview having listview inside not working properly

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I am having a listview inside the Gridview and trying to set the OnitemClickListener on gridview. It works when clicked outside the listview, but on clicking the listview part of gridview item its not working.

Following xml code i am inflating in gridview item.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dashlet_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dashlet_settings"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/settings" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#c3c3c3" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dashlet_settings_items_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the `listview` component has no click listener.If you want to get click listener for `listview`,you may need to put it.

Commonly we are using `setOnItemclickListener` for listview. 
The clicking position has `listview` only. That is why you get nothing while clicking.

Comment: i dont want to have setOnItemclickListener on listview but on gridview item and listview here is part of the view of GridView item